# Issue with all MySQL SELECT queries containing EXISTS subquery and LEFT JOIN with ON where ON has reference to external SELECT

Tags: mysql, mariadb, left-join

This is the problem. When running **any** query of that type

```
SELECT field1
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT table2.field2, table3.field3, table3.field4
              FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.field3 = table2.field2 
                                           AND table3.field4 = table1.field1
              WHERE "some condition");
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown column 'table1.field1' in 'on clause'
```

On the other hand, this query

```
SELECT field1
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT table2.field2, table3.field3, table3.field4
              FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.field3 = table2.field2 
              WHERE "some condition"
                AND table3.field4 = table1.field1);
```

works fine.

There are possible alternatives, for example it can be inner join rather than outer join, negative subquery check (not exists), where clause is not necessary and field list can be different. The only critical part is EXISTS subquery and reference to table1.field1 under ON condition from JOIN.

I tried it on several MySQL and MariaDB servers with the same result! Also tried to find **exactly the same** issue online and here on SO - no success.

As per suggestion given in one of the comments, I modify the question with a real example.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `browser` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `browsers` (               
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `browser` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

And to get all users who used all browsers, I run this query

```
select distinct user_id
from sessions as t1
where not exists (select t2.id, browsers.id
                  from sessions as t2 LEFT JOIN browsers ON t2.browser = browsers.browser 
                                                         AND t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                  where browsers.id IS NULL);
```

Error message I get:

```
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 't1.user_id' in 'on clause'
```

And of course the desired output I need is select query result set with a listing of users.

I know how to rewrite the query for this particular task, so this is not a problem. The problem is to run the query with this pattern for any other task since it seems very logical and good SQL.

My question is what I am doing wrong and if that is a bug, how I can avoid it keeping the same query structure.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the second version is what I would always use, and I'll bet you would never to write the first version.

Comment: But they are not the same logic! The first version was based on real development task and real issue, that's why I started testing it on other servers with other tables. Of course there was a possibility to solve the issue different way, but this solution was fully intuitive and normal in terms of SQL logic. This is very confusing

Comment: I don't have a documentation reference, but maybe it isn't possible.  My point is that there is probably a way to write your query without doing this.

Comment: Sure, a particular query most likely can be rewritten, if not, alternative solution can be found. But my question is about a pattern of queries that we cannot run for some reason I do not understand.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Comment: My "Please in code questions" comment is my standard one so not all of it is relevant to this post but is relevant to future posts. Please put everything necessary to your question in your post, in text where possitble. (I have a standard comment re that too.) PS I thought I posted (I certainly prepared) a comment quoting the MySQL manual that prior to a certain version correlated query nesting, contrary to the standard, was limited; & saying to read the manual re functionality you are using; & saying that there are many easily found SO posts re this. (I have a standard comment re that too.)

Comment: yes you did and I sent an answer, your comment was wrong, I flagged it and it was removed by moderators with my answer :-) your comment was about derived tables, but my question is about subqueries. For derived tables - yes they do not support external data references and this is a bug fixed in recent mysql. For subqueries - they do support references and it does not work only with "JOIN" under "ON" condition. It works under "AND" and "WHERE" conditions. And if this is a bug, it's never reported. I consider this as bug, but ask community in case I am wrong or in case someone can explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have met bug#96946, MySQL does not allow outer references in the JOIN ON clause.

If I am not mistaken, this is a rewrite of a double-nested NOT EXISTS query, and I think this statement will actually be accepted in MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM sessions AS s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM browsers AS b
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM sessions s2
                                    WHERE s1.user_id = s2.user_id AND
                                          s2.browser = b.browser
                                   )
                 );
```

Comment: Interesting... I was not able to find this bug with my keywords and also the query there is slightly different since they use derived table rather than subquery and reference is not really "outer". Well, it's outer to the nested query, but same level to JOIN tables. In my query reference is external to JOIN tables from subquery. BTW, a link to this question was added there as a comment and error number / message is the same, so there is some relation between bugs.

Comment: Right, this nested "not exists" looks like the solution to avoid the bug and right a query accepted by MySQL. Similar solution with "exists" above. But I added this post for two reasons: maybe someone can find a bug with exactly issue I describe or in case I did some mistake and mysql aware of this type of query.

Comment: There's also a briefer validation from Sep 26 in that bug.
In addition, there's at least one duplicate bug: 35242. So you're not the first to bump into this limitation...

Comment: Sep 26 is more relevant since it's about subquery! Bug you found (35242) is exactly the one (extra join on external query doesn't count). This was my point: I did not bring extraordinary query, so it was confusing no one brought the topic to SO or even to MySQL. I don't remember my search query on google, but subject **Unknown column 't2.i2' in 'on clause**  would be too generic to find. Well, looks like the question is answered! Hm... 11 year old bug and MySQL did not make an attempt to fix it...